# Is it possible to legally visit uninhabited islands in the Pacific for a couple of days/weeks?

Tags: legal, nature-and-wildlife, islands, oceania

Can you sail to any island, and anchor your boat there, and use the island for food?

Comment: I'm sure it depends on exactly which island, and which country it belongs to.

Comment: Therefore the answer to "any island" with respect to the proposal's legality would probably have to be "no"...but some specific islands might allow this – not that I would know of any. Do you have any particular islands or archipelagos in mind?

Comment: Many of the uninhabited islands are reserves and visiting them needs a special permission from the countries they belong to.

Comment: Regarding "use the island for food", in many cases, I think the island will use you as food.